# Append string to url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to append a string to url using the body? Something similar to the JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/qXs77/

```
<a href="#" onclick="extendSearch('&page=2');return false">hi</a>
```

I want to append this query to the url: `?q1=iPodTouch&x=79&y=20`

When the user clicks the link they will be taken to the next page with the attached string above.

Comment: Try putting `location.href += "url: ?q1=iPodTouch&x=79&y=20"` inside the onclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** :

No need to pass it on another function ,

Use like this:

```
<a href="http://xxxxxx.com/xx-xxxxxx" onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?q1=iPodTouch&x=79&y=20';return false">Navigate</a>
```

Comment: The string isn't attached to to the next page. I changed the href to the url of my site and there's no string.

Comment: it attached you can see it by opening `jsfiddle` result : As `View Frame Source`
view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:%20?q1=iPodTouch&x=79&y=20

Comment: in the href I added a url but when I save and click the link it doesn't have the string

Comment: Which browser you use? my side both my DEMO works correctly..m using Chrome

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: So,please post your whole code so,i'll check it ,where error occurs ??

Comment: It's not attaching to the url of my next page

Comment: Give me your actual URL in which you can put this code ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48203/discussion-between-user2680614-and-ashish-mishra)

Comment: Please join the chat so I can show you the actual url

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to utilize jQuery more you could try this approach.

```
$('a[data-page]').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).data('page');
  location.href += ( location.search.length ? '&' : '?' ) + 'page=' + page;
});
```

and have the HTML look like:

```
<a href="#" data-page="2">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: Does this attach to the url of the next page?